# How do I get an elements sibling in JQuery, in a function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to set an element to have the same value as its sibling in JQuery.

I have a table with a number of fields in, and when I click an Edit button I want to copy the value of a label to it's neighbouring input field:

```
<table style="width:90%">
  <tr>
    <td>Start</td>
    <td>
       <span ID="lblSprintStart" class="staticField">01/01/2001</span>
       <input class="editableField" id="sprintStart" />
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>End</td>
     <td>
       <span ID="lblSprintEnd" class="staticField">02/02/2002</span>
       <input class="editableField" id="sprintEnd" />
     </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
<button id="editButton">Edit</button>
```

I can do it by targeting each individual element by ID:

```
$(function () {
 $("#editButton")
  .click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   editMode();
 }); 
});

function editMode() {     
  $("#sprintStart").val($("#sprintStart").siblings(".staticField").html());
}
```

But I want to do it by class so all fields are updated. If I change the function to use the $(this) selector and do it by class it doesn't work:

```
function editMode() {     
   $(".editableField").val($(this).siblings(".staticField").html());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QQLvX/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QQLvX/2/

Comment: You aren't passing `this` to the `editMode()` function which is why the second version of `editMode()` that is trying to use `this` doesn't work as `this` is reset on each function call.  I'd suggest passing the starting point as an argument to `editMode(where)` and using that.

Comment: Essentially the same as [How to reach the element itself inside jQuery’s `val`?](/q/16710521/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**.val( function(index, value) )**](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value)

> A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

Code

```
$(".editableField").val(function(){
    return $(this).siblings(".staticField").html();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QQLvX/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each()`

```
$('.editableField').each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).siblings(".staticField").html());
});
```